# Enabling the previously consumed text to be matched again in Java

Tags: java, regex

```
program A {
   int x = 10;
   tuple date {
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;
   }
}

function B {
    int y = 20;
    ...
}

process C {
    more code;
}
```

I'd like to extract whatever is inside the outer curly braces for `program`, `function` and `process`. In terms of the output, I want to see three matches:

```
       int x = 10;
       tuple date {
                int day;
                int month;
                int year;
       } //first match

       int y = 20;
       ... //second match

       more code; //third match
```

I've achieved this using Javascript. The regular expression I use is `/(program|function|process).*?{(.*?)}\n+(program|function|process)/m`, which works as demonstrated by [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/D6FMq4TX8M).

However, when I use the same expression in Java it wouldn't work any more. It only returns the first match. I have a vague memory that the consumed text in a previous match will not be matched again. In my case, the keywords `program` and `function` have been consumed in the first match, resulting in no further matches. Is there a way in Java to match the consumed text?

**Edit**: the Java code is posted below as requested.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String input = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("input.txt"));
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(program|function|process)[^\\{]*?\\{(.*?)\\}\\s*(program|function|process)", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the code you are using to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)..so your regex would be

```
(?<=program|function|process)[^{]*\\{(.*?)\\}\\s*(?=program|function|process|$)
```

**Group 1** would have your data..

Comment: I know it may extract what I want. But my question is, how can I reuse the previously consumed text in another match?

Comment: @TerryLi you can use back-reference..so `\1` would refer to group1 `\N` would refer to group N..

Comment: @TerryLi i have made a couple of changes in your regex..I have added `$` so that you can match the last `{}`..

Comment: Thanks. I think _lookaround_ is what I'm looking for.